# Проблема при создании dll библиотеки

Tags: winapi, visual-studio, c++, dll

Здравствуйте. Учусь создавать dll библиотеки. Создал два проекта Win32 - один просто приложение, а другой - DLL библиотека. В проекте с DLL библиотекой добавил заголовочный файл и файл исходного кода.

```
// HeaderDLL.h (заголовочный файл библиотеки)

#ifndef MYDLLH
#define MYDLLH

extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) int Function();

#endif

// SourceDLL.h (исходник библиотеки)
#include "HeaderDll.h"
#include <stdexcept>

extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) int Function()
{
    return 5;
}
```

В проекте с приложением добавил исходник с таким содержимым:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE   hInstance,          
                    HINSTANCE   hPrevInstance,      
                    LPSTR       lpCmdLine,          
                    int         nCmdShow)       
{
    HMODULE hLib;
    // Загрузка библиотеки
    if(hLib = LoadLibrary("HaVA.dll")) {
        return 0;
        MessageBox(0, "Error", "Error load a library", MB_OK);
    }

    int (*pFunction)();
    (FARPROC &)pFunction = GetProcAddress(hLib, "Function");
    int n = pFunction();

    FreeLibrary(hLib); // Выгрузка библиотеки
    return 0;
}
```

Библиотеку положил в один каталог с проектом, в общем проблема такая - при запуске программы вылетает сообщение о том,  что программа завершилась некорректно. Как я понял, эта ошибка появляется во время приравнивания pFunction() переменной n. В чём ошибка? Что я неправильно делаю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте по порядку.
В модуле программы, которая вызывает функцию из библиотеки нужно правильно объявить указатель на функцию (у Вас это pFunction). Объявление правильно сделать так. Сначала объявляем нужный нам тип (для удобства дальнейшего использования):

```
typedef extern "C" _declspec(dllimport) int (*PFunction)();
```

После загрузки библиотеки нужно создать указатель на функцию и сохранить в нем адрес этой функции:

```
PFunction pFunction = (PFunction)GetProcAddress(hLib, "Function");
```

и **обязательно** проверить что адрес получен успешно (**pFunction != 0**). Если всё ОК вызываем её:

```
int n = (*pFunction)();
```

Почему Ваша программа завершается аварийно. Это ясно из приведенного Вами сообщения о возникновении исключения. Переводя на наш язык можно сказать что Ваша программа пыталась обратиться по нулевому указателю и это вызвало исключение по защите памяти. Это в, свою очередь, говорит о том что указатель pFunction == 0, т.е. в библиотеке не была найдена нужная Вам функция. Произошло это по причине неверного объявления вызываемой функции в Вашей программе (см. выше).

Про экспортирование функции. Создавая dll для Windows Вы должны указать линкеру, что какие-то функции из этой библиотеки должны быть доступны внешним программам. Это можно сделать с помощью добавления в объявление функции вот таких слов: **_declspec(dllexport)**, что у Вас уже и сделано.

Comment: Переписал как вы сказали. Вместо typedef extern "C" я написал extern "C" typedef (Наоборот), т.к. компилятор ругался. Но без толку. Ошибка всё равно та же вылетает.
Мой переписанный исходник. 
http://pastie.org/4084632

Comment: Проверьте, не С++, а именно Си main работать будет. 

Кстати, библиотеку Вы делали Си компилятором (или крестами) ?

Совсем уж дурь, но напоследок проверьте с именем функции со всеми **маленькими** буквами (винда же ведь).

Comment: _stdcall должно помочь. Тоесть попробуйте в дллке объявить функцию так:
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) int _stdcall Function();
а в вызывающей программе так:
typedef _declspec(dllimport) int _stdcall (*PFunction)();
PFunction pFunction = (PFunction)GetProcAddress(hLib, "Function");
кстати hLib у Вас в этом месте нормальный? И после вызова GetProcAddress чему равен pFunction?

Comment: Не компилит если дописать то, что вы написали.
hLib нормальный. 
Я не могу узнать чему pFunction равно, т.к. если я начинаю что либо с ним делать, сразу появляется ошибка, которая описана в комментариях в первому ответу.

Comment: **printf()** тоже не работает ???

    printf("pFunction = %ld\n",(long)pFunction);

я просто не знаком с VisualStudio и не знаю у Вас 32 или 64-bit

в Linux я напишу

    int (*fu)();
    printf ("fu = %p\n",fu);

в таком виде gcc нормально воспримет указатель в любой разрядности

Answer (score 0):

```
 int (*pFunction)()  - указатель на функцию

 int n  -  целочисленный тип
```

У вас идет неявное( при чем грубое ) преобразование `int (*pFunction)()` к `int`. Поэтому, скорее всего, компилятор выдает вам ошибку из-за этого. А вообще хотелось бы взглянуть на то, **что выдает вам компилятор**...

---

Говорю прямо, **могу ошибаться**. Если это так, то поправьте кто-нибудь меня пожалуйста.

---

Честно говоря, ваш код немного смущает меня( думаю, не только меня ). Вот это, например, не знаю, как понимать:

```
if(hLib = LoadLibrary("HaVA.dll")) {
    return 0;
    MessageBox(0, "Error", "Error load a library", MB_OK); // return же...
}
```

Надеюсь, библиотека экспортирует функцию "Function". Не просто содержит, а **именно экспортирует**:

```
 (FARPROC &)pFunction = GetProcAddress(hLib, "Function");
```

Comment: Вот что выдает компилятор: Необработанное исключение в "0x00000000" в "used_dll.exe": 0xC0000005: Access violation.

А на счет экспортирования функции - не понимаю о чём вы.
А return - ошибся чуток:)

Comment: http://www.hostmake.ru/articles/c/240/

Определяется макроконтстанта EXPORT. 

    #define EXPORT extern "C" __declspec (dllexport)

    EXPORT int CALLBACK MyFunction(char *str);

Comment: @Asen, декларация указателя на функцию, возвращающей целое у ТС **правильная**. Именно

    int (*func)();

Инициализация этого указателя и вызов:

    func = strcmp;
    int result = func("xaxa","xoxo");

Эквивалентно

    int result = strcmp("xaxa","xoxo");

Comment: @avp, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется что беда в этом куске:

```
 int (*pFunction)();//Вот тут! Поправьте если не прав, но это вроде как раз и производит что то типа call [0x0000] что и вызывает "необрабатываемое исключение в 0x00000000"
    (FARPROC &)pFunction = GetProcAddress(hLib, "Function");
    int n = pFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, как в винде, но может простой пример из Linux окажется полезным.

Файл tmain.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

#define fatal(msg) do { fprintf(stderr,"%s: %s\n",msg,dlerror()); \
                        exit(-1); } while (0)

main ()
{
  void *lib;
  if (!(lib = dlopen("./libdyn-simple-test.so",RTLD_LAZY)))
    fatal("dlopen");
  int (*funchello)();
  funchello = dlsym(lib,"hello");
  if (!funchello)
    fatal("dlsym");
  int rc = (*funchello)();

  printf ("rc = (*funchello)(); rc = %d\n",rc);
  rc = funchello();
  printf ("rc = funchello(); rc = %d\n",rc);
}
```

Файл hello.c из него делаем libdyn-simple-test.so (аналог dll)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
hello ()
{
  int rc = printf ("Hello, I'm hello() !\n");
  return rc;
}
```

Компилируем и запускаем

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/ig/tst/tdlib$ gcc -c -fPIC hello.c 
avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/ig/tst/tdlib$ gcc -shared -o libdyn-simple-test.so hello.o
avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/ig/tst/tdlib$ gcc -o tmain tmain.c -ldl
avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/ig/tst/tdlib$ ./tmain 
Hello, I'm hello() !
rc = (*funchello)(); rc = 21
Hello, I'm hello() !
rc = funchello(); rc = 21
avp@avp-ubu1:~/src/ig/tst/tdlib$
```